# how to use python pdfkit with python flask webapp

Tags: javascript, python, flask, web-applications, pdfkit

I try to get an agreement file (ex:agreement.HTML), convert it to a PDF file and download that file to the users computer.

I want to use PDFkit module, get the html file on my webapp and download the generated pdf to the local user.

How is that possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: tried pdfkit to print google.com but i want to print form http://blabla/admin/groupsale/customer/printindividualagreement/?applicant_id=27&group_sale_id=31    so to do this i have to be in the system. how to get agreement from my system to module

Answer (score 2):

Like this example below, set project directory like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mshz0.png)

this the code for **app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import pdfkit
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['PDF_FOLDER'] = 'static/pdf/'
app.config['TEMPLATE_FOLDER'] = 'templates/'


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/convert')
def konversi():
    htmlfile = app.config['TEMPLATE_FOLDER'] + 'index.html'
    pdffile = app.config['PDF_FOLDER'] + 'demo.pdf'
    pdfkit.from_file(htmlfile, pdffile)
    return '''Click here to open the
    <a href="http://localhost:5000/static/pdf/demo4.pdf">pdf</a>.'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Demo pdfkit</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h2>Flask PDFKit</h2>

   <table border="1">
      <tr>
         <th width="90">ID</th>
         <th width="250">Title</th>
         <th width="150">writer</th>
         <th width="170">Publisher</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>B001</td>
         <td>Learning Flask Framework</td>
         <td>Matt Copperwaite</td>
         <td>PACKT Publishing</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>B002</td>
         <td>Flask By Example</td>
         <td>Gareth Dwyer</td>
         <td>PACKT Publishing</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>B003</td>
         <td>Essential SQLAlchemy</td>
         <td>Rick Copeland</td>
         <td>OReilly</td>
      </tr>
   </table>

   <p><a href="http://localhost:5000/convert">Convert to PDF</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

or you can just use code like this:

```
import pdfkit

# from file
pdfkit.from_file('templates/index.html', 'demo_from_file.pdf')

# from string
pdfkit.from_string('Hello World', 'demo_from_string.pdf')

# from url
pdfkit.from_url('https://www.google.com/', 'demo_from_url.pdf')
```

Comment: How can do if i want to pass data inside index.file and use djinja to display before generated the pdf file.

Comment: @BostonKenne This [link](http://www.marknagelberg.com/creating-pdf-reports-with-python-pdfkit-and-jinja2-templates/) might help

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no need to really save the file. Here is my code for generating a web page and returning it as an pdf:

```
html = render_template(
            'webpage.html'
        )


options = {
    'page-height': '297mm', 
    'page-width': '210mm',
}

resp = Response(pdfkit.from_string(html, options=options),
               mimetype="application/pdf",
               headers={"Content-Disposition":
                            "attachment;filename=outfile.pdf"})
```

Comment: I'd like to have this option, but when I try from_string or from_file, I get an error:
`missing 1 required positional argument: 'output_path' `

Comment: Nevermind, I realized I had pdfkit 0.6.1 installed. Upgrading to 1.0.0 solved my problem.